# How can I enable GTK+ for OpenCV in cmake?

Tags: opencv, cmake, gtk

Host: UBUNTU (Linux 4.15.0-47-generic x86_64)

Target: i.MX 8QuadXPlus (Linux imx8qxpmek 4.9.88-imx_4.9.88_imx8qxp_beta2+g05f46d3)

I`m already make **WITH_GTK** and **WITH_GTK_2_X** enable.

But after Configure,
GTK+ still NO.

How can I enable GTK+ for OpenCV in cmake?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev
```

If after that you still can't enable the options, try with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-devel
```

Comment: Thank you, but still failed

Comment: Oh, I see you are cross compiling for ARM64. Are you going to compile every library yourself? This is going to be difficult. If you install a base system on your embedded system with projects like Buildroot, Yocto or Arch Linux ARM it is going to be much simpler and you can follow this: http://studiow.cf/blog/post/how-to-cross-compile-opencv-for-armbian-with-gtk. This targets Armbian but you can easely adapt for your needs.

Comment: Finally, I succeeded.
I took a raspberry pi 3 to compile opencv libs.
Then use your method to let GTK enable.
Finally put the SO files into the embedded system.

Answer (score 2):

you need to make sure Qt is disabled before GTK3 support is possible

**( -D WITH_QT=OFF )**

Answer (score 1):

@lb90 and @incubo4u correct

Writing it to new ones who come across this issue

Install gtk3 in case not installed [source](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/linux/#installing-gtk3-from-packages)

`sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev`

It is always `QT` OR `GTK`, if you enable one the other is automatically disabled

This should give you an idea which one you would like to build opencv with [GTK or QT when build OpenCV](https://answers.opencv.org/question/215066/gtk-or-qt-when-build-opencv/)

This is the official page for the same [GUI backends (highgui module)](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d05/tutorial_config_reference.html#tutorial_config_reference_highgui)

```
-D WITH_QT=OFF \
-D WITH_GTK=ON \
```

OR

```
-D WITH_QT=ON \
-D WITH_GTK=OFF \
```

If you turn `ON` **GTK** OpenGL support is turned **OFF** by default