problem to build OpenCV 4.9.0 with highgui module: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with
I try to run the following code in C++17:
#include <opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp>  
#include <iostream>

int main() {  
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);  
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {  
        std::cerr << "Error: Could not open camera" << std::endl;  
        return -1;  
    }  
  
    cv::Mat frame;  
    cv::namedWindow("Camera Output", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);  
  
    while (true) {  
        cap >> frame;  
  
        if (frame.empty()) {  
            std::cerr << "Error: Could not capture frame" << std::endl;  
            break;  
        }  
  
        cv::imshow("Camera Output", frame);  
  
        if (cv::waitKey(1) == 'q')  
            break;  
    }  
  
    cap.release();  
    cv::destroyAllWindows();  
  
    return 0;  
}

This code must implement showing a video captured from a camera. For managing connected libraries I use the CMake tool and its CMakeLists.txt file in a project. Here is a content of the CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)  
project(opencv_4_9_0_test)  
  
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)  
  
set(OpenCV_DIR "/home/me/opencv-4.9.0/build/opencv2")  
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)  
message(STATUS "OpenCV library status:")  
message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")  
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")  
message(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")  
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})  
  
add_executable(opencv_4_9_0_test main.cpp)  
  
target_link_libraries(opencv_4_9_0_test ${OpenCV_LIBS})

The OpenCV library has been used of 4.9.0 version, taken from the official website, and compiled from source codes. The compilation has been successful. On running a code below:
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>  
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "OpenCV version : " << CV_VERSION << std::endl;  
    std::cout << "Major version : " << CV_MAJOR_VERSION << std::endl;  
    std::cout << "Minor version : " << CV_MINOR_VERSION << std::endl;  
    std::cout << "Subminor version : " << CV_SUBMINOR_VERSION << std::endl;  
      
    return 0;
}

I get an expected output. But the problem is with running the code above after a successful compilation, here is the text of an error to be thrown:
/home/me/CppProjects/opencv_4_9_0_test/cmake-build-debug/opencv_4_9_0_test
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.9.0) /home/me/opencv-4.9.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:1255: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvNamedWindow'


Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6:SIGABRT)

So I've installed the two packages libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, and re-compiled the OpenCV but the problem has remained. Afterwards I've extracted the library in a new folder opencv-4.9.0_ from a distibuted archive and corrected one CMakeLists.txt file string:
set(OpenCV_DIR "/home/me/opencv-4.9.0_/build/opencv2")

But the problem has been the same. It's strange in the showing error text it refers to the /home/me/opencv-4.9.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:1255 that has to be with opencv-4.9.0_. So I've cleaned and then rebuilt the project but the problem has been still remained. By the way, it's okay for the Python or Java analogous code, the built-in graphics works.
What things can be done to resolve the problem?

and re-compiled the OpenCV but the problem has remained. Did you do a clean build and use CMake to regenerate? I ask because if you don't have CMake regenerate the Makefile I would not expect it to add support for gtk after it had already disabled it.

This question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58370077/how-can-i-enable-gtk-for-opencv-in-cmake

@drescherjm Thanks. I even created a new project. It didn't help.

cmake-gui to browse all the cmake variables, to generate, ...

I even created a new project. When you created the new project did you enable gtk since that may not be enabled by default?
